# Code Executing Too Late?

Tags: php, mu-plugins

I created an mu-plugins folder with this block of code in it:

```
if ( $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] === "domain1.com" ) { $sitetype = one; }
if ( $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] === "domain2.com" ) { $sitetype = two; }
if ( $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] === "domain3.com" ) { $sitetype = three; }
```

Basically, what I want to do is assign a `$sitetype` (basically a category) to a wordpress site and change things up based on the current domain name.

The code I have in my wordpress header file is:

```
if ( $sitetype == all ){ echo "site type 1"; }
if ( $sitetype == viral ){ echo "site type 2"; }
if ( $sitetype == woman ){ echo "site type 3"; }
```

With the 1st code block, it doesnt work when inside the mu-plugins folder but if i move it right above the 2nd code block in the header file it works fine so i think its executing incorrectly while in the mu-plugins folder.  Is there a way I can keep the code in the mu-plugins folder and to get this to work the same way?

Comment: You need to declare it global `global $site_type;` in both places before using.

Comment: @bonger can u put it as an answer so i can mark this as correct in case someone else comes across this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per comments, declare it global before using in both (or all) places:

```
global $sitetype;
if ( $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] === "domain1.com" ) { $sitetype = one; } //etc
```

and

```
global $sitetype;
if ( $sitetype == all ){ echo "site type 1"; } //etc
```